# how to print a for loop output into a text file?

Tags: python, loops, printing

i'm making a number list generator and i want to print the output as a list in a .txt file but it always just prints the final value for the variable. here's my code :

```
zero = ["000000","00000","0000","000","00","0",""] 
for x in xrange(0,999999):
    with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write("011"+zero[len(str(x))] + str(x)+"70")
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: ... `'011{:06d}70'.format(x)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reopening the file for each number. Every time you do that, it empties the file unless you use `a` mode.

You should open the file once, then do the loop inside that.

```
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for x in xrange(0,999999):
        text_file.write("011"+zero[len(str(x))] + str(x)+"70")
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file for writing erases the file first. Open the file *then* loop.